# np.where overwriting th values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to create a derived column from two other columns in a pandas dataframe using np.where.

```
df['END_TIME'] = np.where(((df['TYPE'] == 'BOLUS') & (df['DESCRIPTION'] == 'rocuronium')),  df['START_TIME'] + dt.timedelta(minutes=30), None)
df['END_TIME'] = np.where(((df['TYPE'] == 'BOLUS') & (df['DESCRIPTION'] == 'vecuronium')),  df['START_TIME'] + dt.timedelta(minutes=45), None)
```

but what is happening is when I run the second line of np.where condition, it clears the first result values of the first np.where.

```
DESCRIPTION   TYPE            START_TIME
rocuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-26 05:32:00
rocuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-26 05:38:00
vecuronium    NOT BOLUS   2018-04-26 14:59:59
vecuronium    NOT BOLUS   2018-04-26 15:59:59
vecuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-27 07:50:00
```

This is the actual dataframe and now I am trying to create a new derived column based on type and description. When I run the first np.where statement the resulting dataframe would be:

```
DESCRIPTION   TYPE            START_TIME           END_TIME
rocuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-26 05:32:00   2018-04-26 06:02:00
rocuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-26 05:38:00   2018-04-26 06:08:00
vecuronium    NOT BOLUS   2018-04-26 14:59:59
vecuronium    NOT BOLUS   2018-04-26 15:59:59
vecuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-27 07:50:00
```

Which is good. But if I run the second np.where statement the resulting dataframe looks like.

```
   DESCRIPTION       TYPE             START_TIME         END_TIME
    rocuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-26 05:32:00   
    rocuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-26 05:38:00   
    vecuronium    NOT BOLUS   2018-04-26 14:59:59           None
    vecuronium    NOT BOLUS   2018-04-26 15:59:59           None
    vecuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-27 07:50:00     2018-04-27 08:35:00
```

I don't know why I am losing the data of first np.where statement data.

Expected dataframe:

```
DESCRIPTION   TYPE            START_TIME           END_TIME
rocuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-26 05:32:00   2018-04-26 06:02:00
rocuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-26 05:38:00   2018-04-26 06:08:00
vecuronium    NOT BOLUS   2018-04-26 14:59:59       None
vecuronium    NOT BOLUS   2018-04-26 15:59:59       None
vecuronium    BOLUS       2018-04-27 07:50:00   2018-04-27 08:35:00
```

I tried to create the following function and call it:

```
def add_roc(df):
    if (df['TYPE'] == 'BOLUS') & (df['DESCRIPTION'] == 'rocuronium'):
        df['END_TIME'] = df['START_TIME'] + dt.timedelta(minutes=30)
        return df
```

and it throws the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.select` for multiple conditions. This will generalize well for many conditions. The `pd.to_datetime` is because things get coerced to an int.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cond_lst = [df['TYPE'].eq('BOLUS') & df['DESCRIPTION'].eq('rocuronium'),
            df['TYPE'].eq('BOLUS') & df['DESCRIPTION'].eq('vecuronium')]
choice_lst = [df['START_TIME']+pd.Timedelta(minutes=30),
              df['START_TIME']+pd.Timedelta(minutes=45)]

df['END_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(np.select(cond_lst, choice_lst, default=pd.NaT))
```

#### Output:

```
  DESCRIPTION       TYPE          START_TIME            END_TIME
0  rocuronium      BOLUS 2018-04-26 05:32:00 2018-04-26 06:02:00
1  rocuronium      BOLUS 2018-04-26 05:38:00 2018-04-26 06:08:00
2  vecuronium  NOT BOLUS 2018-04-26 14:59:59                 NaT
3  vecuronium  NOT BOLUS 2018-04-26 15:59:59                 NaT
4  vecuronium      BOLUS 2018-04-27 07:50:00 2018-04-27 08:35:00
```

---

In this case, because of the dichotomous variable in the `'TYPE'` column, I'd favor `where` + `map`.

```
d = {'rocuronium': pd.Timedelta(minutes=30), 
     'vecuronium': pd.Timedelta(minutes=45)}

df['END_TIME'] = df['START_TIME'].where(df.TYPE.eq('BOLUS')) + df.DESCRIPTION.map(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.loc[df['DESCRIPTION'].isin(['rocuronium'])]
df = df.loc[df['TYPE'].isin(['BOLUS'])]
```

You should get what you need :))